# Lumen SoapClient not found

Tags: laravel, soap, soap-client, lumen

please help me.
I try to using SoapClient in Lumen 5.7 but it's always getting error

[lumen soapclient not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOwKm.png)

But when I try using Laravel it's success.

could someone help me and tell me how could I using SoapClient in Lumen?

FYI I have install soap extension in my php.

Comment: If you already installed soap client in your server  you will see soap after this command in your terminal `php -m`

Comment: Have you tried this library: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap